# Pasar una tupla como parámetro de múltiples id en el "where" en petición delete mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Tengo 2 peticiones.

En la primera recibo una dupla con todos los id que quiero borrar (también podría recibir los datos como lista), algo así:

```
hoy = datetime.today().date()
cursor.execute("select id from citas where dia < ? and paciente is null", (hoy,)) =

tupla = (226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242,
243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306)
```

Con la segunda quiero hacer un delete de filas de una tabla.

Lo pude hacer pasándolos por un for y haciendo una petición por cada elemento de la tupla:

```
for dato in tupla:
  conexion.execute("delete from citas where id = (?)", (dato))
```

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer una sola petición y pasar la tupla como variable?

¿Se puede pasar la tupla como parámetro para que se haga en una sola petición?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes probar con el operador "[IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)", y convirtiendo la tupla en un string.
Debería quedarte algo así:

```
conexion.execute("DELETE FROM citas WHERE id IN {}".format(str(tupla)))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia que tenia que ser un string, habia probado con
Habia hecho lo mismo pero con la tupla y con una lista